# Error Connecting to Database WHEN Installing Wordpress on XAMPP [Tried All the Usual Stuff] (Pics Included)

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, mysql, installation, xampp

Here's the error I get

https://gyazo.com/56134064606564c836ae8b0f18a129ba

Here's the DB login settings I used:

https://gyazo.com/2facfe11765bc4b887c31bc111bb123a

Here's my DB names and users:
https://gyazo.com/2e009a5d37e87ba1e094ed0b6c826af6

What I tried so far:

- Enabled all permissions, assigned them to all dbs, removed the need for passwords and usernames
- tried setting the host name to local under login information

Background:
 - to set up XAMPP i had to set mysql porn to 3307 since 3306 was causing issues.  I tried to set define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:3307' ); in the wp-config-sample.php file.  Is there any other place I can set port for wordpress?

Comment: Please, upload your images to [imgur](https://imgur.com/) and [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/348712/edit) your question to make images visible right on the WPSE site. See _Images_ section on the [Markdown Help page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to set the host as localhost:3307  not just localhost.

Like so https://gyazo.com/3aa87d040d9953171da69b196d04f4d1